# Let $v \in R^{k}$ ,with $v^{T} v \neq 0$ . Let $P=I-2 \frac{v v^{T}}{v^{T}v}$, where $I$ is the $k X k $ identity matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $v \in R^{k}$ ,with $v^{T} v \neq 0$ . Let $P=I-2 \frac{v v^{T}}{v^{T}v}$, where $I$ is the $k \times k $ identity matrix. Then prove that eigenvalue of $P$ are $1,-1$ and $P^{2}=I$

$P^{2}=(I-2 \frac{v v^{T}}{v^{T}v})(I-2 \frac{v v^{T}}{v^{T}v})$

=$(I-4 \frac{v v^{T}}{v^{T}v}+4\frac{v v^{T}}{v^{T}v} *\frac{v v^{T}}{v^{T}v})$

Don"t know how to proceed further !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: note that since $v^Tv$ is a scalar, $$I - 4 \frac { v v ^ { T } } { v ^ { T } v } + 4 \frac { v v ^ { T } } { v ^ { T } v } * \frac { v v ^ { T } } { v ^ { T } v } =  I - 4 \frac { v v ^ { T } } { v ^ { T } v } + 4 \frac { (v ^ { T } v ) v v ^ { T } } { (v ^ { T } v)^2 }.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: why is $v^{T}v$ a scalar is a matrix of order $1 x 1$

Comment: What is a $1 \times 1$ matrix if not a scalar?

Comment: but how is thos multiplication defined v is of order (k x 1)

Comment: then $(v^{T}v )v v^{T}$is of order (1 x k)(k x1) *(k x 1)(1xk) =(1X1)

Comment: You may wan to double check that math.  Since $v$ is a vector, scalar multiplication is defined in the usual way.  Note that $(v^Tv)vv^T$ s of order $(1 \times k)(k \times 1)*(k \times 1)(1 \times k) = (1 \times 1) * (k \times k)$. If it is not clear, try working out an example with an actual vector.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from your work, note that $vv^\top vv^\top = v(v^\top v) v^\top = (v^\top v)(vv^\top)$ since $v^\top v$ is a scalar.
So 
$$\frac{vv^\top}{v^\top v} \frac{vv^\top}{v^\top v}
= \frac{vv^\top}{v^\top v}.$$

---

Hint for the eigenvalue question: What is $Pv$? What is $Pw$ when $w$ is orthogonal to $v$? Can you construct a basis of $R^k$ consisting of eigenvectors?

Comment: $(v^{T}v )v v^{T}$is of order (1 x k)(k x1) *(k x 1)(1xk) =(1X1) but $(v v^{T})(v v^{T})$ is of order KxK

Comment: @sejy $(k \times 1)(1 \times k)$ is $k \times k$.